# Refused visa from USA now applying for New Zealand visa

Tags: visas, new-zealand

I applied for a USA visitor visa last year but was refused. After that I got married to New Zealand resident. Now I am applying for New Zealand visitor visa. Can the USA's refusal affect my New Zealand visitor visa application?

Answer (score 2):

Question F4 of the [New Zealand Visitor Visa application](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/NR/rdonlyres/6A5C188E-11CE-4DB0-BF5D-D55010BDF5BE/0/INZ1017.pdf) reads:

> Have you, or has anyone included in this application, ever been refused a visa/permit to visit, work, study or
>   reside in any country? `[]` Yes `[]` No

As you have been refused a US visitor visa, you must answer "Yes" to this question. (If you lie and answer "No", you'll have bigger problems.) Saying "Yes" does *not* mean you will be automatically refused, but you will have to explain what happened. The section below then reads:

> If you have answered yes to any of the questions above give full details. This includes full details of any charges,
>   convictions and the sentence or penalty imposed. Continue on a separate piece of paper if necessary.

This is where you will explain what happened when you applied for a US visitor visa, and why you were refused (if you know that information).