# Can a visa refusal affect you applying visa in other countries

Tags: visa-refusals

Applying for a Canadian visa and it was refuse . Can this have implications on you applying for other countries visa ?

Comment: Do you mean it was *refused*? Refuse as a noun means *trash*.

Comment: Yes my  Canadian student visa was refused and I have plan applying for a vacation visa to the USA with my wife ,hope this will not affect application or what are your  advise?

Comment: Earlier: *[Applying for other visas after Canadian visa refusal?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71505/)* and *[How can a visa refusal affect my future travel plans?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38751)*; there are many similar questions like *[Refused visa from USA now applying for New Zealand visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65216)*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can, among the US, Canada and UK.

[UK/USA: Agreement for the sharing of visa, immigration and nationality information](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/agreement-between-the-uk-and-usa-for-the-sharing-of-visa-immigration-and-nationality-information)

[Immigration Information Sharing Agreement Between Canada and America](https://www.us-immigration.com/blog/immigration-information-sharing-agreement-between-canada-and-america)

Additionally, many Visa applications ask if you've ever been refused.  You must answer truthfully.

However, there is generally nothing wrong with applying because even if a previous refusal is considered, you will have the opportunity to overcome that.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the reason for a refusal is likely to have a bearing on the degree to which that refusal is likely to affect other applications.

Comment: @phoog I though about that as a Student Visa is quite different from a Visitor Visa, but I really have no idea if that's the case.  But stated none the less.

Comment: I was thinking more about different reasons such as (for example) failing to prove nonimmigrant intent as opposed to deception, where the latter will be much harder to overcome than the former.  The fact that different reasons have different applicability to different visa types is also something to consider, of course.